# How to see the files stored in Hive/Impala metadata

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, impala

I am facing the following error when trying to execute `compute incremental stats <table> PARTITION(<partition-column>='value')`:

```
WARNINGS: Disk I/O error: Failed to open HDFS file hdfs://dummy/path/partition1=value1/partition2=value2/partition3=value3/part-00000-33c8985a-6a51-40a8-90cb-e3fabac7ca44-c000", 
Error(2): No such file or directory
Root cause: RemoteException: File does not exist: /dummy/path/partition1=value1/partition2=value2/partition3=value3/part-00000-33c8985a-6a51-40a8-90cb-e3fabac7ca44-c000
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:66)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.INodeFile.valueOf(INodeFile.java:56)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocationsInt(FSNamesystem.java:2101)        org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:2071) 
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getBlockLocations(FSNamesystem.java:1984) 
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.getBlockLocations(NameNodeRpcServer.java:581)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.getBlockLocations(AuthorizationProviderProxyClientProtocol.java:92)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.getBlockLocations(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:376)
    org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:617)
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1073)
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2281)
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2277)
    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1920)
    org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2275)
```

The file is not present, so I assume this is a metadata issue. I have tried `refresh <table>` and `invalidate metadata <table>` but it is not working.

So, I have two questions:

- Where is the file info stored? Is there a way to see the list of files stored in Hive/Impala metadata?
- Any ideas on how to revolve the issue?

Comment: you can see partition file location using this command `show partitions table_name;` How to resolve this issue - i think the table is not created properly - its pointing to dummy file location which seems odd. If you crate a table with proper table location, may be it will work.

Comment: the table is working fine, and I know the location of the table. The file is not there. Probably was erased from spark or similar. What I dont know is where the reference to that file is stored to be able to clear it.

Comment: i think you can control while creating table. Its hdfs file system so you may not see it from command prompt.